# Convolutional Neural Network has 1.7% explained variance score after days of tweaking structure and hyperparameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, chess

I'm attempting to create a convolutional neural network that takes in a chess board position and evaluates it, spitting out a centipawn number.

My dataset is a sample of 5,000 chess games of grandmasters, each expanded to every position that occurred in the game (1 sample for e4, 1 sample for e4 e5, etc until checkmate). The only feature is an 8x8x6 array for each board, the 6 being a 1, 0, or -1 depending on whose piece is there, with indexes referring to each type of piece ([1,0,0,0,0,0] is a pawn), and the 8x8 matching the board squares.

I'm aware for chess this is kind of a small sample of the positions--I have a larger dataset of more games but it will take a long time to process so my goal was to get a workable model before spending the time and computing power on preprocessing it.

My approximately best performing model, after days of tweaking, is this:

```
# model configuration
# takes in a board input and outputs a centipawn value
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import L1, L2
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import MeanAbsoluteError
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import GlorotUniform
log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose = 1, patience = 50)
adamOpti = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False,
    name='Adam')
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
initializer = GlorotUniform()
regularizerl2 = L2(l2 = 0.1)
EPOCHS = 5000

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(36, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(8,8,6), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizerl2))
model.add(Conv2D(36, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", kernel_regularizer=regularizerl2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer=initializer, kernel_regularizer=regularizerl2))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
# , metrics=[MeanAbsoluteError(name='mean_absolute_error', dtype=None)]
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adamOpti)

# training
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = EPOCHS, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), batch_size=1024, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, early_stop])
```

I've tried varying the number of fully connected and convolutional layers, but larger numbers of both seem to increase overfitting. My original neural network didn't have regularization or the batch normalization, both of which help somewhat but nothing remarkable. I've tweaked the learning rate and number of neurons per layer. No matter what I do, it seems to never have a particularly substantive impact on the performance of the neural network. Below is the mean squared error of my latest model, which also had a mean absolute error of 470.374 centipawns (ranging from -10000 to 10000, but most positions only within -1500-1500)
[image]

I'm not sure if my approach is wrong, my hyperparameters/structure are off, my data representation is wrong, or something else. I would appreciate if someone with more knowledge in chess programming or convolutional neural networks could help me out.

EDIT: 1 thing I hadn’t considered— the dataset includes both white and black turn positions, evaluated with turn data by stock fish, however the positions are fed to my neural network without turn data.

Comment: 0.017440670314153528 is the explained variance score

Comment: You are not training the network for enough epochs, the loss is still decreasing after 100 epochs

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I trained it for another 300 epochs after that and it does indeed increase after that. Apologies for not including a more total graph.

Comment: Its not about including a graph, a common mistake is not to train your network for long enough, until the loss converges and stops decreasing

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I've updated the graph. The picture I put in my question originally was the second time I had run that model, set to a specific number of epochs, estimated from the first run for the point of convergence. The loss had converged and substantively increases after the point shown on the previous graph.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a week or two and I've trained a new, larger dataset. I'm unsure if the structure of the network or format of the data could be improved to solve the issues, but the same convolutional neural network is achieving fantastic results on the new data set, so the issue and extreme overfitting seem to be a result of insufficient data--with chess in particular, even 800,000 samples cannot encapsulate sufficient positions.

Comment: Indeed your dataset was too small compared to the number of features. The first thing is to add new samples (which you did). You must have at least, I may say, 700 samples per class, or even more.